# YUI JS minifier mess up code

Tags: yui, obfuscation, bundletransformer

I'm using BundleTransformer.Yui.Minifiers.YuiJsMinifier in asp.net MVC 4 project, but I think it's YUI compressor bug...

```
...
var varName='...';
alert(varName); //alert('...')
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function (t, s) {
alert(varName); //alert(t);
}
```

When BundleTrasformer minify & obfuscate this code using YUI compressor variable varName becomes t, and function parameter t stays t, so varName get's overwritten with t...
checkout commented alert...
My question is should I change compressor, or maybe rename all one, and two letter variables into longer ones? Am I doing something wrong? 
if I just change one line of code, all is OK, so I'm pretty sure it's YUI compressor bug

```
...
var varName='...';
alert(varName); 
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function (data, s) {
alert(varName); 
}
```

PS
I know it's not good practice to have one letter variable names, but it's still YUI compressor bug...
PPS:
I'm using eval inside succes function. (Know that's not good practice also, but still, YUI compressor shouldn't break up the code :/)

Comment: can you show your version of code and the minified one? Basically YUI Compressor is a parser which removes whitespaces, removes comments and renames long variable names with short ones, and it does this in a smart way, considering variable scoping and so on based on many many use cases. Those use cases should be quite normal in order to have a functional minified code. So what I'm trying to say is that Yahoo's engineers were more focused on making the minifier work as expected on "quite normal" cases rather than asking themselves about "strange" use cases, because there can be alot of them!

Comment: I can't give you complete code, but this is whole important part...

Answer (score 0):

The `varName` variable is global, and therefore it's name is not processed.

You need to make it local. To do this, wrap the code in a IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression):

```
(function(){
    ...
    var varName='...';
    alert(varName); 
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    success: function (data, s) {
    alert(varName); 
    }
})();
```